# What's the right way to query multiple associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

My application models a writing competition, with `Users`, `Stories`, `Competitions` and `Submissions`.

Users can participate in competitions through submissions, or as owners. I'd like one query or method that returns all competitions owned or participated in by a user. I've got a method returning those as an array, `competitions | owned_competitions`, but I'd really like to keep them ActiveRecord entities so I can chain, apply scopes, etc.

Is there a way to do that, or a better way to setup these relationships?

My models look like this:

user.rb:

```
has_many :stories
has_many :submissions
has_many :competitions, :through => :submissions
has_many :owned_competitions, :class_name => "Competition"
```

story.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :submissions
has_many :competitions, :through => :submissions
```

competition.rb:

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'user_id'
has_many :submissions
has_many :competitors, :through => :submissions, :source => :user
has_many :stories, :through => :submissions

scope :expiring_today, lambda { where("deadline = ?", Date.today) }
```

submission.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :story
belongs_to :competition
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I searched through about 40 other questions trying to understand the best practice and didn't resolve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is absolutely possible. Actually, it's probably possible without even writing any SQL, but I don't know precisely how.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
Competition.joins('left join submissions on submissions.competition_id = competitions.id').where('competitions.user_id = :uid OR submissions.user_id = :uid', :uid => user)
```

We use a left join (rather than the default inner join) so that we can still return competitions that a user owns but which have no submissions yet.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I defined it as a class method on the User model. Do my models and relationships make sense, or is there a better way to setup this set of relationships?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your models and associations, but in the end the real test is not "does this look logical?", it's "does this make it easy/efficient to do what I need?".